# Elliptic curves with the same Galois representation

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, elliptic-curves, galois-representations

Fix a prime $p$. If two elliptic curves over $\mathbb{Q}$ have the same p-adic Galois representation, then what relatinships do we know between them? Any references are welcome.

Comment: Galois group of whom acting on whom?

Comment: @schematic_boi I mean the p-adic representation

Comment: at a single prime, or all primes simultaneously?

Comment: @schematic_boi  at a single prime is enough, will all primes simultaneously be too complicated?

Comment: I am not quite sure. But could you state explicitly on what set/vector space/scheme/whatever your Galois group is acting? Torsion points, $l$-adic cohomology, $p$-adic etale cohomology, algebraic de Rham cohomology, something else maybe.

Comment: @schematic_boi The action of $Gal(\mathbb{\bar{Q}}/(\mathbb{Q})$ on the  p-adic etale cohomology

Comment: I see. I at first thought that you were base changing the curve to $\mathbb{Q}_p$ and acting from there.

Comment: OK, I am not an expert, not even a half of an expert, but maybe see here: https://mathoverflow.net/q/41931/138661

Comment: I think Tate module (for $p$) is dual to etale cohomology with $\mathbb{Z}_p$-coefficients, so if you consider a single prime $p$ and Tate modules are isomorphic (as Galois modules), then your curves are isogenous.

Comment: @schematic_boi you are right, thanks!

Comment: I think you are asking about the Tate conjecture (Faltings isogeny theorem).

Comment: I concur, they are isogenous, by the theorem of Faltings.

Comment: If instead the $\mathbb{Z}_p[G_{\mathbb{Q}}]$-module $T_pE$ is meant, then I think it may even determine the curve up to isomorphism.

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich Often, yes, but not always. If there are isogenies of coprime degrees between the two different elliptic curves then the integral Tate modules are isomorphic. This can only happen for CM curves.